# ApacheNifi - Is there any way to send one flowfile at a time? (one for each minute)

Tags: validation, data-structures, apache-nifi, flowfile

Good Night!

Is there any way to send one flowfile at a time? (one for each minute)

illustration for the ***accumulated files*** :

[image]

I have 138 flowfiles and I want to send 1 flowfile per minute.

Is there one processor or mode to execute 1 per minute?

Thanks!

Comment: set schedule for splitjson processor to 1min

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in any processor, just set the scheduling to 1 concurrent task and run schedule to 1 min or 60 sec

[image: Configuration]